# How to make custom 404 page in routing system

Tags: php, class, routes

I want to make a 404 error page on this routing. How can this be done?

**index.php**

```
<?php

    include 'route.php';
    include 'control/about.php';
    include 'control/home.php';
    include 'control/contact.php';

    $route = new route();

    $route->add('/', function(){
        echo 'Hello, this is home pageeees';
    });
    $route->add('/about', 'about');
    $route->add('/contact', 'contact');

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($route);

    $route->submit();

?>
```

**route.php**

```
<?php


class route 
{   

    private $_uri = array();
    private $_method = array();

    /**
    *Builds a collection of internal URL's to look for
    *@parameter type $uri
    */

    public function add($uri, $method = null)
    {
        $this->_uri[] = '/' . trim($uri, '/');

        if($method != null){
            $this->_method[] = $method;
        }
    }

    /**
    *Makes the thing run! 
    */

    public function submit()
    {

        $uriGetParam = isset($_GET['uri'])? '/' . $_GET['uri'] : '/';

        foreach ($this->_uri as $key => $value)
        {   
            if(preg_match("#^$value$#",$uriGetParam))
            {
                if(is_string($this->_method[$key]))
                {   
                    $useMethod = $this->_method[$key];
                    new $useMethod();
                }
                else
                {
                    call_user_func($this->_method[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex in mind I would just add `$route->add("/.+", function()...);` **after all your other routes**.

Proof: https://3v4l.org/nk5PZ

---

But you could also program some logic which evaluates custom 404-Pages when not being able to find a correspondig route.

For example:

```
private $_notFound;

public function submit() {
    $uriGetParam = isset($_GET['uri'])? '/' . $_GET['uri'] : '/';
    $matched = false;
    foreach ($this->_uri as $key => $value) {   
        if(preg_match("#^$value$#", $uriGetParam)) {
            if(is_string($this->_method[$key])) {   
                $useMethod = $this->_method[$key];
                new $useMethod();
            } else {
                call_user_func($this->_method[$key]);
            }
            $matched = true;
        }
    }
    if(!$matched) {
        if(isset($this->_notFound)) {
            if(is_string($this->_notFound)) {
                $action = $this->_notFound;
                new $action();
            } else {
                call_user_func($this->_notFound);
            }
        }
    }
}

public function notFound($callback) {
    $this->_notFound = $callback;
}
```

Then you'll have to add the 404-action by `$route->notFound(function... or "class");`